# Scatter plot on large amount of data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Let's say i've got a large dataset(8500000X50). And i would like to scatter plot X(date) and Y(the measurement that was taken at a certain day).

I could get only this: 
[image]

```
data_X = data['date_local']
data_Y = data['arithmetic_mean']
data_Y = data_Y.round(1)
data_Y = data_Y.astype(int)
data_X = data_X.astype(int)
sns.regplot(data_X, data_Y, data=data)
plt.show()
```

According to somehow 'same' questions i've found at Stackoverflow, i can shuffle my data or take for example 1000 random values and plot them.
But how to implement it in such a manner that every X(date when the certain measurement was taken) will correspond to actual(Y measurement).

Comment: Although, do you think you'll be able to make more sense of 8500000 points plotted on a graph than 8500?

Comment: I'd recommend using a heatmap, so you don't need to get rid of data and you can have a better visualization.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## First, answering your question:

You should use [`pandas.DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html#pandas-dataframe-sample) to get a sample from your dateframe, and then use [`regplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html#seaborn-regplot), below is a small example using random data:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

dates = pd.date_range('20080101', periods=10000, freq="D")
df = pd.DataFrame({"dates": dates, "data": np.random.randn(10000)})
   
dfSample = df.sample(1000) # This is the importante line
xdataSample, ydataSample = dfSample["dates"], dfSample["data"]

sns.regplot(x=mdates.date2num(xdataSample.astype(datetime)), y=ydataSample) 
plt.show()
```

On `regplot` I perform a convertion in my X data because of datetime's type, notice this definitely should **not** be necessary depending on your data.

So, instead of something like this:

[image]

You'll get something like this:

[image]

---

## Now, a suggestion:

Use [`sns.jointplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.jointplot.html#seaborn-jointplot), which has a `kind` parameter, from the **docs**:

> kind : { “scatter” | “reg” | “resid” | “kde” | “hex” }, optional
>
> Kind of plot to draw.

What we create here is a similar of what matplotlib's hist2d does, it creates something like a heatmap, using your entire dataset. An example using random data:

```
dates = pd.date_range('20080101', periods=10000, freq="D")
df = pd.DataFrame({"dates": dates, "data": np.random.randn(10000)})

xdata, ydata = df["dates"], df["data"]
sns.jointplot(x=mdates.date2num(xdata.astype(datetime)), y=ydata, kind="kde")

plt.show()
```

This results in this image, which is also good for seeing the distributions along your desired axis:

[image]